# How to add two vertical lines to plot and color between them?

Tags: gnuplot

I want to highlight a period in my plot by adding two vertical lines and coloring between them. Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to fill a rectangle like this:

```
set object 1 rect from  0,0 to 1,1
set object 1 rect fc rgb "cyan" fillstyle solid 1.0
plot sin(x)
```